# Toggle button values on and off status should be store to databse

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I am working with app that will have toggle button and I want to store on and off values in Database without using Edit Text  can u tell me the process for this.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a simple App that displays 3 buttons which when clicked toggle saving the state in an SQlite database.

It consists of 3 pieces of code (designing each would be a process to be followed):-

1. The layout which has 3 buttons activity_main.xml
2. The DatabaseHelper, which has the core database code and provides methods that can be used to add (insert), update and query rows DatabaseHelper.java.
3. The activity which manages the user interface MainActivity.java

## activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggle3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## DataabseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydatabase"; // The name of the database (the file name)
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1; // The SQliteOpenHelper class provides a means of managing versions so verion nmber is required

    //publicly availavle constants for the toggle states
    public static final int TOGGLESTATUSON = 1;
    public static final int TOGGLESTATUSOFF = 0;

    // The table and the columns
    public static final String TABLE_TOGGLE = "toggle";
    public static final String COL_TOGGLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // using _id allows CursorAdapater to be used
    public static final String COL_TOGGLE_STATUS = "toggle_status";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB; // The database connection

    // The Constructor
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION); // Call the super constructor
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase(); // store the connection
    }

    // This is called ONCE when the database is created. Used here to create the table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //The SQL for creating the table
        String crt_toggle_table_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TOGGLE + "(" +
                COL_TOGGLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL_TOGGLE_STATUS + " INTEGER " +
                ")";
        // Execute the sql
        db.execSQL(crt_toggle_table_sql);
    }

    //No Version management included
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // Add a row to the table (sets the button state to ON)
    public long addToggleRow() {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TOGGLE_STATUS,TOGGLESTATUSON);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_TOGGLE,null,cv);
    }

    // Retrieve all rows
    public Cursor getToggleRows() {
        return mDB.query(TABLE_TOGGLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    // Update a row, as per the provided id, toggling the value
    public void toggleToggle(long id) {
        mDB.execSQL(
                "UPDATE " + TABLE_TOGGLE + " SET " + COL_TOGGLE_STATUS + " = NOT " + COL_TOGGLE_STATUS + " WHERE " + COL_TOGGLE_ID + " =?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)} // the arguments to be bound 
                );
    }
}
```

## MainActivity.java (managing the UI)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Class variables for the Buttons (3) and the DatabaseHelper object
    Button[] mButtons = new Button[3];
    DatabaseHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instantiate the DatabaseHelper (will create it when first run)
        mDBHlpr = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        initialiseDBToggleRows(); // Add the rows to the table, 1 per button, if not already added

        // set the array of buttons
        mButtons[0] = this.findViewById(R.id.toggle1);
        mButtons[1] = this.findViewById(R.id.toggle2);
        mButtons[2] = this.findViewById(R.id.toggle3);

        // Get the buttons states from the database setting the button text to ON or OFF
        loadButtons();

        // Add the onCLickListeners to 
        //      a) update the respective row in the database (toggle it)
        //      b) refresh the button display
        for (int i=0; i < mButtons.length;i++) {
            final int current = i;
            mButtons[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDBHlpr.toggleToggle((long)current + 1);
                    loadButtons();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Set the button text according to the values tored in the database
    private void loadButtons() {
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr.getToggleRows();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            if (csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TOGGLE_STATUS)) == DatabaseHelper.TOGGLESTATUSON) {
                mButtons[csr.getPosition()].setText("ON");
            } else {
                mButtons[csr.getPosition()].setText("OFF");
            }
        }
    }

    //Add a row, if no rows exist, for each button in the mButtons array
    private void initialiseDBToggleRows() {
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TOGGLE) > 0) return;
        for (int i=0; i < mButtons.length; i++) {
            mDBHlpr.addToggleRow();
        }
    }
}
```

## Result

The App when installed looks like :-

[image]

Clicking any Button will toggle it from ON to OFF or from OFF to ON, the state is stored in the database so stopping the App and restarting maintains/restores the last state (unless the App is uninstalled or the App's data is cleared/deleted).

Comment: this is the process for sqllite iam working on mysql databse

Comment: @user9961587 then your question should have specified as such. However, all that is needed is to replace the methods in the DatabaseHelper with methods that connect to and issue the appropriate commands to the MySQL server and change the invocation of those methods accordingly.

Comment: bro  i am a fresher can u expalin that it will help  to me

Comment: A search on **mysql for android** would help you.

Comment: yes i have searched bro but there is no method using  without taking edittext box  to send the value to databse i know the process of notmal inserting databse mathod i want to send toogle button status on and off  values to database without using edittext bro can u help me